# How to delete a question based on typo-like problem that I asked, with an answer that isn't my own?

Tags: discussion

**[I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444772/how-to-concatenate-values-using-aggregate-functions-in-ssrs-2008-r2-in-a-textbox) that I will summarize simply.**

I had a misnamed dataset, not with a typo, but having the incorrect name.  It's just like a typo problem, in that if I had reviewed it more carefully, I might have noticed it and not needed to ask the question.   Someone provided an answer, it can't be deleted.

The question is of little use to anyone other than seeing the lesson of "check your names before posting" played out one MORE time.

**What happened:**

I posted the question and within a few minutes, someone was kind enough to assist me.  I started attempting their solution when I noticed the error in the names.  So I let the user know who answered, that I misnamed the dataset.  Then attempted to delete the question, not wanting to waste anyone else's time.

I couldn't delete it, because it had an answer.  So I provided another answer, the true answer.  Then flagged it for moderator attention.

It was put on hold as off-topic, as it should.  I was able to accept my answer now that two days has passed.

I am basically asking, at the risk of wasting more time on the same question, in an attempt to SAVE time in the future.  What can be done to avoid this?  Assuming the post has been made already.  **Is there some way to REMOVE these once another user submits an answer?**  To avoid having to even have a moderator waste time on it?

**My thoughts and reasoning:**  skip from here down if you are not interested.

If I knew what was wrong with my code at all, I wouldn't post the question, I'd just fix that issue and move on.   It's the nature of asking questions. You have to be willing to ask at some point. Perhaps while continuing research, or after exhausting your research, and changing tasks.. regardless,
I rarely post questions because I can do the research if I know what I'm looking for.  In that specific case, I couldn't find anything else to read on it, and needed people's experience.

If I can't solve a problem, it's either I am ignorant of a function existing that already does what I'm attempting, ignorant of some syntax, unaware of some other factor, or have some little mistake somewhere in the code I'm unaware of.  The common factor being that I'm unaware of what is the problem, and have to seek guidance in the chance that it's one of the first 3 options.  ie, I can read an error code and get to the bottom of it without help in most cases. Or at least search for functions and read what they do.

In this question, I believed there may have been a limitation of the function or an exception where it couldn't perform what I was attempting.  So I risked taking another person's time to help me and asked a question.

I'm already extremely hesitant to post questions on SO for a number of reasons.  I just don't want to be MORE hesitant because there is ALWAYS a risk of there being a mistake like this one, especially on inherited code. I value people's time greatly and would rather not risk wasting anyone's time if I couldn't delete a question over something like this, I'd just not post it at all.

For what it's worth, both names were correct in some place on the project, so they looked valid to read them. The project was inherited and passed through many individuals' hands before me, all using different naming protocols. "ins1data" vs "insdata1", both used repeatedly in different contexts.  I DID check the names is my point.  I checked them repeatedly before posting.   AND, within 30 minutes of posting the question I struggled for many hours attempting to solve on my own, it was solved, as an indirect result of the help someone here provided me.  So, I'm glad I posted it, but it doesn't belong here and I want to be responsible for that and let no one else have to see it, or any question in the future like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to delete it, or just assume you couldn't?

> Someone provided an answer, it can't be deleted.

From the [Deleted Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) section of the Help Center:

> Users can delete their own questions if the question:
>
> - has zero answers
> - only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes
>
> Simply click the delete link underneath the question.

Assuming it's your question from a couple days ago about reporting services, you *should've* been able to delete it. Before you posted your own answer, there was only one answer with no upvotes.

Comment: I tried to delete it.  For whatever reason, I wasn't able to the other day.  Possibly, the notice that you shouldn't delete too many questions or you might get banned from asking them deterred me.  Regardless, I was able to delete it this time once my answer was removed.  I know I was very tired at the time, so maybe I winced at the warning.  I just recall a message saying I couldn't since it had answers.  I might have also tried to delete it after I posted mine, and in confusion of sleepiness, forgot the order.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't think your question and the answers to the question have any value, you can flag your question using the *other* reason for moderator attention. Make sure to write a short and concise reason for why it should be deleted. As long as the moderator agrees that it doesn't add any value to the site, and no one besides you has any upvotes they'll likely delete it. Sometimes even if others have upvotes, they may delete it too, but lot easier probably for them when no one has any upvotes.

Also, your question is already closed. So if you unaccept your answer, and leave the question with no accepted answer, and the score of the question and each answer is 0 or less, then it will be automatically deleted after 9 days of being closed due to the [ROOMBA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/244519).

Comment: Didn't know about that it would be deleted automatically also after 9 days of being closed.